# Python encoding wrong after ubuntu localisation

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

After i changed ubuntu localisation from EN to RU i faced problem that cause python console (when i debuging Odoo) prints some strange codes insted of russian text like this:

\u0414\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0438 \u043e\u0448\u0438\u0431\u043a \u0438:
\u042d\u043b\u0435\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442 '' \u043d\u0435 \u043c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u0442 \u043d\u0430\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0432 \u0440\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043c \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435

Instead of this:

Детали ошибки:
  Элемент '' не может находится в родительском виде

What i can do to avoid such problem ?

Comment: Please share your code. Have you inserted the correct encoding on the top of your `.py` file?

Answer (score 0):

Prepared by @APIuz team

```
#For python3

import json
import io
text = '\u0414\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0438 \u043e\u0448\u0438\u0431\u043a\u0438: \u042d\u043b\u0435\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442 '' \u043d\u0435 \u043c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u0442 \u043d\u0430\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0432 \u0440\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043c \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435'

io.open("APIuz.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8").write(json.dumps(text, ensure_ascii=False))
print(open("APIuz.txt", "r").read())

#For python2

print(repr(u'\u0414\u0435\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0438 \u043e\u0448\u0438\u0431\u043a\u0438: \u042d\u043b\u0435\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442 '' \u043d\u0435 \u043c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u0442 \u043d\u0430\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0432 \u0440\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043c \u0432\u0438\u0434\u0435').decode('unicode-escape'))

#The code is just what you think

#>>> "Детали ошибки: Элемент  не может находится в родительском виде"
```